# Brew vs system version of python packages with pip

Tags: python, pip, homebrew

Although *pip* on the path is pointing to the brew version:

```
08:01:40/shared $which pip
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/bin/pip
```

When using pip it seems to be invoking the system version instead:

> 22:54:40/shared $pip install matplotlib
>
> Requirement already satisfied
>   (use --upgrade to upgrade): matplotlib in
>   **/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages** Cleaning up...

That location is for the system python.  Does brew share the same location for its packages  with the system (I would presume not)?

*Update*  as requested here is path:

> $echo $PATH
>       /Users/steve/Applications:/shared/sfk:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:
>   /usr/local/mysql/bin:/shared/bin:.:**/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/bin**:/shared/maven3/bin:
>   /shared/jruby/bin:/shared/scala/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.6.0/bin:
>   /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.6.0/sbin:/shared/hbase-0.98.8-hadoop2/bin:
>   /shared/ruby-1.8.7/bin:/shared:.:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin

Comment: the pip obtained from `sudo easy_install pip` has worked best for me. It installs into `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: Run ``echo $PATH`` and paste the output here, please.

Comment: @pzp updated OP with path

Comment: Your path looks correct; it's strange that it's not working properly. Have you tried @kilojoules suggestion?

Comment: Actually, my pip also is installing to" /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages". Maybe it's normal behavior...

Comment: `$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin`

Comment: It looks like you're still using the system version of Python

Comment: @kilojoules The PATH is shown in OP: it has the brew version first.